# lodash equivalent of groupBy in Underscore

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

What is the lodash equivalent of the groupBy function in underscore?

```
 var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40},
                {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
 underscore.groupBy(stooges, 'age');
```

fetches

```
=> {
  "40": {name: 'moe', age: 40},
  "50": {name: 'larry', age: 50},
  "60": {name: 'curly', age: 60}
}
```

The [migration docs](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Migrating) doesn't mention any equivalent of groupBy

I tried doing lodash.keyBy() but it gives the corresponding value of each key is the last element responsible for generating the key.
Any clue?

Comment: Lodash has a [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) method as well.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. Thanks anyhow